# Including the schema name when calling a PL/SQL procedure doesn't work in one schema but does in another

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This problem came up when trying out the Unit Testing capabilities of SQLDeveloper.

When running a test for a procedure that is created within my schema I am seeing an error however when the same procedure is run in one of the oracle supplied schemas it works without an issue.

SQL Developer generates the following calls:

1) This one doesn't work (error is shown below):

```
BEGIN
 "IANC"."SIMPLE_PARAMETER"(P_X => 123);
END;
```

2) This one does:

```
BEGIN
 "HR"."SIMPLE_PARAMETER"(P_X => 123);
END;
```

This is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SIMPLE_PARAMETER 
(
  P_X IN NUMBER  
)
IS
BEGIN

  null;

END SIMPLE_PARAMETER;
```

The following is the output from SQLPLUS, where you can see when the procedure is run in my schema I see an error whilst when running the same procedure in another schema the procedure works as expected:

[image]

In case of need my I am using Oracle Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.1.0

**Update**

Screen shot showing procedure signatures

[image]

I should also mention that if I remove the schema name from the procedure call then the procedure runs and completes as expected.

Thanks in advance for any help received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the SIMPLE_PARAMETER procedure in IANC is the same (or at least has the same signature) as the one in HR?  What do you get from `DESCRIBE "IANC"."SIMPLE_PARAMETER".

(P.S. since your identifiers are all upper-case, you shouldn't need the double quotes at all.)

**Added**: Another possibility is that you have a package called IANC in the IANC schema, so Oracle is looking for a procedure in that package called SIMPLE_PARAMETER that does not exist.  Example:

```
SQL> exec bigdecimaltest

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec dcosta.bigdecimaltest

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create or replace package dcosta as
  2  end;
  3  /

Package created.

SQL> exec dcosta.bigdecimaltest
BEGIN dcosta.bigdecimaltest; END;

             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
PLS-00302: component 'BIGDECIMALTEST' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This seems like buggy behavior -- if the attempt to resolve the name as package.member doesn't succeed, I think Oracle ought to then try it as schema.object, but it looks like once it has found a match on the package name it won't reconsider that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave, I have added a screen shot showing the signature of the procedure for the two schemas. I hear you where say about the double quotes but this is the code that SQLDeveloper generates when running its unit tests. If I manually remove the schema name and run the procedure it works as expected.

Comment: Do you have a package in the IANC schema that is also called IANC?  That could be causing confusion with the name resolution.

Comment: Thanks Dave - I didn't have a package but I did have a table called IANC (left over from some long forgotten experiment!) Dropped the table and the problem went away. Thanks a lot for your help.